# User control with enumerable datasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, datasource

I'm trying to create a user control which has a DataSource, which can accept any form of collection, such as `List<string>` or `string[]`

If I check for `is IEnumerable` then it requires a type, checking `is IEnumerable<Type>` returns false, as does `is IEnumerable<object>`

What's the correct way to go about this? I presume I set the `DataSource` property to `object` and then check on the setter for the correct type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want `DataSource` to be the non-generic `IEnumerable`. Any `IEnumerable<T>` is also an `IEnumerable`, which allows you to enumerate the collection without the strong typing that the generic interface gives you.

.NET 4.0 introduces covariance, so you can assign a `IEnumerable<Dog>` to a variable of type `IEnumerable<Animal>`. However, if you want to allow any type in the data source, you'd still need to make DataSource an `IEnumerable<object>`. You can't do anything with an `IEnumerable<object>` that you can't do with an `IEnumerable`.